# nessus-service consuming more than 80% of CPU with Montery 12.2

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, monterey

Ever since my mbp was upgraded from 12.1 to 12.2, the fans are howling non-stop, and the laptop is much hotter than before.

Took a look at Activity Monitor, and it was found nessus-service consuming more than 80% of CPU.

[image]

Is there any possible fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to ask [Tenable](https://docs.tenable.com/nessus/Content/NessusService.htm).  `nessus-service` isn't something that comes with the OS, it's something you installed.

Comment: Just curious why there was no such problem with 12.1 release? I didn't check, but suppose `nessus-service` was also installed with that build?

Comment: Only you can answer when you installed it.

Comment: It's a company laptop, and `nessus-service` was installed by company IT, I believe.